# How to automatically change wallpaper?

Tags: wallpaper

A nice feature of Ubuntu is the Wallpaper changer which can be configured in "Appearance" settings.

[image: Ubuntu's appearance settings]

Is there a possibility to do that with elementary OS?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Another great tool for this is [Variety](https://launchpad.net/variety)
I downloads wallpapers filtered by keyboards unto your computer and changes them in over time. It works great with elementary OS, though you have to adjust the settings to allow Variety to set the greeter wallpaper. Still, it's a third-party ppa so use at your own risk.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peterlevi/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install variety
```

Comment: Which setting do I have to adjust for greeter wallpaper?

Comment: I have the German version, so the translation might be a bit off. There is a tab called "Adjust" (third tab from the right), where you have to mark the option "make sure wallpapers are used in the greeter", than chose "/usr/share/backgrounds/" as  wallpaper folder and make sure it is writable by Variety.

Comment: such a nice handy software

Comment: Variety is available in Loki as part of the Ubuntu standard repo. It will not be the latest version, but should be well enough (current version in Xenial at this time is 0.6.0 while the PPA has 0.6.3, the additional 3 patches may or may not be important to you).

Comment: OK, this tool is all kinds of awesome. I'm seriously considering replacing my usage of the KDE built-in slideshow wallpaper feature (which is great) with this, on my Kubuntu installation.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that's possible with onboard tools.

But there are several 3rd party applications delivering this feature.
You can use [Wallch](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wallch/) for that. You can install it via Software Center.

Comment: I had an issue with Wallch, at first it works nice but after a while it stop working due to unknow reason - switch to variety